# Load UI app in memory without opening browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, in-memory

I have app in which one part is front-end and another one back-end.
All my calculation logic resided in front-end code.

With help of back-end data UI code will get rendered, now we need reporting service implemented where we need image of rendered part, for that need to load UI code in memory without opening browser.

I know node.js has some capability but do we have any other way?
Please provide a guidance which can help me with this issue.